# Show that $f(1)$ is the maximum value of $f(x)=\frac{x^2+x}{1+x^2}$ where $x \in [-1, 1]$ without derivatives

Tags: calculus, maxima-minima

> Let $f: [-1,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ such that
> $$f(x)=\frac{x^2+x}{1+x^2}$$
> Show that $f(1)$ is the maximum value of $f$.

I thought about maybe breaking it down into simpler steps by finding the maximum of $g(x)=x^2+x$ and $h(x)=1+x^2$, which are $1$ and $\{-1, 1\}$ respectively, but I'm not sure how to show that either. We haven't seen derivatives, but we have seen the Bolzano theorem and the Weierstrass theorem.

Comment: For that alone $\,x^2+x \le x^2+1\,$ should suffice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have $f(1)=1$ and\begin{align}1-\frac{x^2+x}{1+x^2}&=\frac{1-x}{1+x^2}\\&\geqslant0,\end{align}since $x\leqslant1$. So, yes, $f$ attains its maximum at $1$.

Comment: Could you please elaborate further? I don't quite understand why $f(1)-f(x) \geq 0$ means $f(1)$ is the maximum value.

Comment: Never mind, I understood why.

Comment: $f(1)-f(x)\geq 0 \forall x\in [-1,1]\Rightarrow f(1)\geq f(x) \forall x\in [-1,1] \therefore f(1)$ is the maximum.